# Qt QML TextEdit component do no get a slidebar when the text is to large to fit

Tags: qt, qml

SDK: Qt Creator 2.4.1

Target: Nokia N9 and Windows 7

If I do the following in a qml file

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.nokia.meego 1.0


Page {
    id: myShowChangeLogPage


     TextEdit  {
        id: changeLogArea
        anchors.top: titleBackground.bottom
        width: parent.width
        height: 300
        text: "1\n1\n1\n1\n2\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n3\n1\n1\n1\n4\n1\n1\n1\n1\n5\n1\n1\n1\n6\n1\n1\n1\n7\n1\n1\n1\n8\n\n\n\n\n9"
        font.pixelSize: 20
        textFormat: TextEdit.AutoText
        readOnly: true
        wrapMode: TextEdit.WordWrap
    }
}
```

The TextEdit area do not behave as I expected.

1. The String will be printed outside the size of the TextEdit area, that is, 
   it continues beneath the bottom screen edge.
2. There is no scrollbar/slider to the right

I was expecting that the the TextEdit element should automatically create a 
scrollbar/slider if the string is to large to fit within the boundaries.

I have been told that TextEdit should do this and there is no need for a Flicker 
or ScrollArea.

I have tried other type of components such as Text and TextEdit and also encapsulate 
the TextEdit in a rectangle without any luck.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I read this right at the beginning of the documentation regarding the [TextEdit](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qml-textedit.html) element:

> Note that the TextEdit does not implement scrolling, following the
>   cursor, or other behaviors specific to a look-and-feel.

There is also a complete example of how to implement scrolling for following the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

TextEdit in qml doesn't implement scrolling. You must to use another one, such as `TextArea` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-textarea.html), then place it inside a `ScrollView`. Here's an example:

```
// Creating a scrollable TextEdit
ScrollView {
    id: view
    anchors.fill: parent

    TextArea {
        text: "TextArea\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n"
    }
}
```